# unexpected token: mapping

Tags: grails, syntax, groovy, data-modeling

I am learning Grails using version 1.3.7 and I keep running into the following syntax error for no apparent reason:

```
unexpected token: mapping @ line x, column y.
```

Once, I got rid of it by running "groovy clean" and "grails clean", but this time it not even that is working. As far as I can tell, my code is exactly like the example in the book I'm using, and yet it keeps complaining about the word "mapping".

Here is an example of one of my classes where it fails:

```
package com.grailsinaction

class Post {

    String content
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
        content(blank: false)
    }

    static belongsTo = [ user: User ]

    static mapping {
        sort dateCreated: "desc"
    }

    static hasMany = [ tags: Tag ]
}
```

What am I missing? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an equals sign... The [mapping line](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl) should read:

```
static mapping = {
    sort dateCreated: "desc"
}
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I discovered that just a minute ago. Gosh, I feel like an idiot. Grails's syntax is so strange to me.

Comment: @Stephan No worries. That line of groovy basically sets the `static` mapping variable to be a Groovy Closure (a kind of anonymous method).  When executed, this calls the `sort` method passing it a map `[dateCreated: 'desc']`.  Just so you know what's going on under the hood :-)  Keep plugging away!  Like any language, it will stick eventually :-)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It certainly isn't all that obvious looking at it coming from Java/C#.